# VIM set column for soft wrap

Tags: macos, vim

[image]In vim I used

```
:set columns=160
```

Now I got a margin on the right side as I have 200 width. But I observed that the last character of a long line touching shows twice. Observe in the image how the spelling of "and" at edge shows "n" twice even when it was typed only once

Is this normal ? As per me this is confusing

I am using OSX with latest VIM

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Edited and attached image. Note "and" has "n" two times at the end

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce it (Linux, vim 7.4)

Comment: @DarkStar: I could reproduce it with macOS Sierra, iterm2 and vim 8. in `:h 'co'` When you set this option and vim is unable to change the physical no. of columns in the display, the display maybe messed up. I reckon that this is happening for us. Could you also tell us your use case?

Comment: Actually my use case is this
I want right side margin like we have on left. I don't like text going up to edge of the vi editor